# Sequelize insert row many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize with Node.js. I was trying to insert data into my many-to-many relationship. According to the documentation we have set[modelName] functions available after the main object has been created. This however doesn't seem to be the case for me. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful. Cheers!

My Student model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db/database');

const Students = sequelize.define('student', {
    studentId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    middleName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    gender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

module.exports = Students;
```

My contact model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db/database');

const Contacts = sequelize.define('contact', {
    contactId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    middleName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    gender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

module.exports = Contacts;
```

my relations:

```
Student.belongsToMany(Contact, {
    through: 'StudentContacts',
    timestamps: false
});

Contact.belongsToMany(Student, {
    through: 'StudentContacts',
    timestamps: false
});
```

My database diagram:
[image]

my code to save the object

```
student = new Student({
            firstName,
            middleName,
            lastName,
            dateOfBirth,
            gender,
            email,
            phoneNumber,
            classId,
            tenantId: req.user.tid
        });

        // create student
        const newStudent = await student.save();
        newStudent
            .setContact({
                firstName: contact.firstName,
                lastName: contact.lastName,
                middleName: contact.middleName,
                dateOfBirth: contact.dateOfBirth,
                gender: contact.gender,
                email: contact.email,
                phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber
            })
            .save();
        console.log('student', newStudent);
```

my postman create:
[image]

Updated code to reflect the suggested answer

```
Student.create(
            {
                firstName,
                middleName,
                lastName,
                dateOfBirth,
                gender,
                email,
                phoneNumber,
                classId,
                tenantId: req.user.tid,
                contact: [
                    {
                        firstName: contact.firstName,
                        lastName: contact.lastName,
                        middleName: contact.middleName,
                        dateOfBirth: contact.dateOfBirth,
                        gender: contact.gender,
                        email: contact.email,
                        phoneNumber: contact.phoneNumber
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                include: [Contact]
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce the ability to associate a product with many tags. Setting up the models could look like:

```
class Tag extends Model {}
Tag.init({
  name: Sequelize.STRING
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'tag' });

Product.hasMany(Tag);
// Also works for `belongsToMany`.
Now we can create a product with multiple tags in the following way:
```

Code use sample

```
Product.create({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Chair',
  tags: [
    { name: 'Alpha'},
    { name: 'Beta'}
  ]
}, {
  include: [ Tag ]
})
```

This example it's with hasMany but it's the same for belongsToMany

Comment: I tried this to see if it works with many-to-many but it appears not. it only execute: : INSERT INTO [students] ([firstName],[middleName],[lastName],[dateOfBirth],[gender],[createdAt],[updatedAt],[classId],[tenantId]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8); Please see edited post above for the added code.

Answer (score 0):

For many to many relations - add[modelName] works.

For example if the model name is `user` the method would be `addUser`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).